# Add manually installed android apps to Google Play account

Tags: google-play-store, installation, side-loading

I regularly install a number of frequently used applications on new android devices.
Since I do this often, I download and the latest versions of these apps and sideload the APKs onto the devices in order to save internet bandwith among other reasons.

The problem I encounter with this is that new applications I install via sideloading do not appear in the user's application list in Google Play even though the apps are free.

How can I get these new apps added to the user's application list?

Answer (score 3):

Sideloaded apps are not linked to Google Play. You will have to update them manually (i.e. sideloading)

What you could do is install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) (needs root), and use its `Attach to Market` feature.

[image]

[Another solution](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-receive-updates-for-side-loaded-market-apps-from-the-android-market-client/) would be to use AppBrain instead of Google Play, because AppBrain scans the apps in your phone, and informs you of any updates.